# Clarification on a circular dependancy

Tags: c++, class

My previous post has already been tagged as a duplication - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960042/lots-of-unreasonable-compiler-errors-c

Ive tried the suggested solutions.
However when forward declaring "class course;", my compiler doesnt seem to recognize the class in the previous files, saying that course(the class) is an incomplete type in every place its mentioned in "student.cpp".

Did I miss the point? how do I resolve the circular dependancy in my code?
(Code in previous post).

"course" is tagged as incomplete in student.cpp

"student.h" -

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class course;
class student{
private:
    string name;
    int id;
    string gender;
    int age;

public:
    int amountofcourses;
    student();
    ~student();

    course **courses;
};
```

"student.cpp" -

```
 #include "student.h"
    student::student(){
    courses = NULL;
    course *courses = new course;
}
```

"course.h" -

```
#include "student.h"
#pragma once

class course{

private:
    string name;
    int num;
    int amountofstudents;

public:
    course();
    ~course();
```

Comment: Please stop abusing this website. You **must** read [ask]!

Comment: I cant see the problem.
Couldnt get to solve my problem in my previous post, so im asking for a clarification.

Comment: Don't post the code from the other question. Post the code that you should have posted in the other question: A [mcve]. Emphasis on **minimal**. Also, describe the steps that you tried to resolve the problem, and how that worked out.

Comment: @user2079303- that's not correct either. the correct thing to do is **fix** the other post, not post a new one.

Comment: @Amit the problem Akra had in previous question appears to be the circular dependency. That's a duplicate question and appropriately closed. If Akra has problems with the solutions described in the duplicate question, then it's OK to ask a new question. But the question still needs the [mcve].

Comment: The other post is closed and I havent resolved my problem.
I edited the code to be minimal.

Comment: @user2079303 - I disagree. That's the purpose of reopening a question. Someone asks a question, the community decide to close it, but the issue is not resolved. The user is supposed to edit the question, explain why it deserves being reopened and let the community do it's part again.

Comment: @Amit Im not sure how the forum works, but it seemed to me that once questions are closed they are very unlikely to be reopened.
Might have gotten the wrong impression.

Comment: Then: a. Read [ask] before posting questions - they won't get closed. b. Start by doing the right thing - fix your question

Comment: @Amit I fixed this one.
Since the previous one is closed and this one is more specific, whats the point in reviving the previous one?

Comment: @Akra The code you have posted here won't even compile. And you still have the exact circular include that you did before.

Comment: For one thing, clean the forum. What's the point of leaving a "bad" question when it can be fixed to become "good"?

Comment: Rather have the previous one deleted then.

Comment: @Amit the message given when a question is closed as a dup is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. **If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.**"   Akra was following the instructions given by the site so please do not make accusations of "abusing the site".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete `#include "course.h"` from student.h, where you don't need it and it is causing a circular dependency, and add it to student.cpp where you actually do need it.

EDIT: Note that this answer was written before the posted code was edited to match half of what I suggest here.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have copied this include from my last post, I removed it from the code and this (updated) code is what im actually asking about.
Regarding your edit - thats what I commented about.

Comment: "... and add it to student.cpp where you actually do need it"

Comment: 1. Create example code that reproduces the problem. 2. Post exactly that code.

Comment: Alright, missed the note to add "course.h" to "student.cpp", that solved it.
Thanks.